# Retrieving images under a specific Div with Mechanize and Ruby

Tags: ruby, image, mechanize

I need to retrieve all the images present under a specific div using Ruby and Mechanize. The relevant DOM structure is as follows:

```
<div id="item_img">
<a href="JavaScript:imageview('000000018693.jpg')">
<img src="/shop/doubleimages/0000000186932.jpg" border="0" width="500" height="500" alt="関係ないコメント z1808">
</a>
<img src="/shop/doubleimages/000000018693_1.jpg"><br><br>
<img src="/shop/doubleimages/000000018693_2.jpg"><br><br>
<img src="/shop/doubleimages/000000018693_3.jpg"><br><br>
</div>
```

So, I initially got all the images after spinning up a new agent by doing:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
page = agent.get ('http://double14.com/shopdetail/000000018693/')
puts page.images
```

This was nice, but it every image on the page (as it should), and seems to strip out the div id above it, making it impossible to decide what comes from where. As a result, I had every image on the page (no bueno).

I got it down to this:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
page = agent.get ('http://double14.com/shopdetail/000000018693/')
node = page.search "#item_img img"
  node.each do |n|
  puts n.attributes['src']
end
```

Unfortunately, that outputs the following -

```
/shop/doubleimages/0000000186932.jpg
/shop/doubleimages/000000018693_1.jpg
/shop/doubleimages/000000018693_2.jpg
/shop/doubleimages/000000018693_3.jpg
```

Is there a way to take the full URL and use that instead? Ultimately, I would like to save these images to a database, but I need the full URL to serialize them to disk for later upload.

Comment: Could you just append the host, like `http://double14.com/shop/doubleimages/0000000186932.jpg`?

Comment: I thought that there might be a way to take the full path name from the site so I could avoid relative path names altogether. If this is all that there is, then that sounds like a valid solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can get the full URL for the images with the #resolve method:

```
require 'mechanize'

mechanize = Mechanize.new
mechanize.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'

page = mechanize.get('http://double14.com/shopdetail/000000018693/')

page.search('#item_img img').each do |img|
  puts mechanize.resolve(img['src'])
end
```

Alternatively you can use the #download method to download them directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it for a collection of images.  In this case the base_uri is the url that you are passing to get.  Let me know if you have any questions.

```
def self.qualify_images(base_uri, images)
    images.map do |image|
      next unless has_src?(image)
      qualify_image(base_uri, image)
    end.compact
  end

  def self.qualify_image(base_uri, image)
    src = image.attributes["src"].value
    if src =~ /^\/[\/]/
      result = "#{scheme(base_uri)}#{src}"
    elsif src =~ /^\//
      result = "#{base_uri}#{src}"
    else
      result = src
    end
    http?(result) ? result : nil
  end

  def self.has_src?(image)
    image.attributes["src"].value
  rescue NoMethodError
    false
  end

  def self.scheme(uri)
    uri = URI.parse(uri)
    "#{uri.scheme}:"
  end

  def self.http?(uri)
    uri = URI.parse(uri)
    uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP)
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    false
  end
```

This will ensure a fully qualified uri for each image.

Answer (score 0):

It will look something like:

```
page.search("#item_img img").each do |img|
  puts page.uri.merge(img[:src]).to_s
end
```